# Total injective relations are always functions?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, binary-operations

I was watching the following video, and around 6:12, he says "Whenever there is a total injective relation, there is always a total injective function" as well.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/proofs/tp3-3/vertical-aecd80da5c9a/

I cannot quite understand this statement because if there are less elements in set A then set B, and its a total injective relation, there needs to be at least one element in set A that maps to two elements in set B, meaning that it is not a "function". Can anyone explain me what he means here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Whenever there is a total injective relation, **there is always** a total injective function" does not mean "Whenever there is a total injective relation, the **exact same relation** is a total injective function". The function that is guaranteed to exist might very well be different from the original relation.

That said, his statement is true *assuming the axiom of choice*. For a total injective relation $R$ on a set $X \times Y$, define a function $f:X \to Y$ in the following way: for each $a \in X$, since there is at least "one arrow out" of $a$ (by his definition of totality) there is at least one $b \in Y$ such that $aRb$ i.e. the set $B_a=\{b \in Y: aRb\}$ is non-empty. Hence, by the axiom of choice, we can choose a unique $b_a \in B_a$. Now simply define $f(a)$ to be this $b_a$. If $R$ is injective, you can check that this function is too. In general, this function $f$ is, of course, not the same as the original relation $R$ from which we constructed it.